# Remove space around divs

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, but there is space *around* them,. I have eliminated the space between them using `overflow: none;`, but I do not know how to eleminate the extra space around them. How can I do that?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/James_Parsons/s8z7dwdq/1/)

Comment: `overflow: none` doesn't eliminate space...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove margin space around body or clear default css styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547291/how-to-remove-margin-space-around-body-or-clear-default-css-styles)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your body's margin needs to be set to 0.

```
body{margin: 0;}
```

Additionally I highly recommend using a CSS reset at the top of your CSS as below to avoid other possible conflicts: 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s8z7dwdq/3/)

```
html, body, body div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, menu, nav, section, time, mark, audio, video, details, summary {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-weight: normal;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        background: transparent;
    }
```

Comment: Why use all these tags instead of *?

Answer (score 2):

The body element has a margin. Remove it with:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/s8z7dwdq/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

The body element has a default margin of 8px. You need to set it to 0 in your css.

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
}
```

As a default, your two div's are wrapped inside a BODY element, which is also wrapped in an HTML element. You don't see this in jsFiddle, because they are generated automatically for you when the you click run.

If you haven't already, I would suggest researching 'CSS Resets' (basically resetting all styling to base-line) and the 'Document Object Model' (DOM). This will help you understand inheritance, HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

Check for margin and padding in your CSS.