# How to remove white space between div elements

Tags: html, css

I created a web page with 3 div tags with some content in each div and with background colors set to the div elements I found some white space appearing between the div elements.
I have tried a lot to remove these white space using various properties like `outline`, `margin`, `padding` etc, but I failed.
I want to remove white spaces between my `div` without using 'float' property. 
[webpage snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3W6E.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
    margin:0px;
    background-color:green;
}
.container
{
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
}
.head
{
    background-color:gray;
}
.nav
{
    background-color:blue;
}
.content
{
    background-color:lime;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="head">
        <h1>Welcome to my page!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <h2>some text</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Some text in content</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The white space is due to your h1,h2,h3,p tags.

Comment: If so then how to remove them without removing the tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove margin space around body or clear default css styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547291/how-to-remove-margin-space-around-body-or-clear-default-css-styles)

Comment: Set your `p`,`h1` and `h2` margins to `0`. check answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
h1, h2, p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Browser adds `margins` on heading elements and paragraphs by default. You remove it via CSS.

Answer (score 4):

The space between your divs is because of default `h` and `p` elements's margins. I added just this css rule to override default margins:

```
h1, h2, p{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Please check this snippet:

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
    background-color:green;
}
.container{
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
}
.head{
     background-color:gray;
}
.nav{
    background-color:blue;
}
.content{
    background-color:lime;
}
h1, h2, p{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="head">
        <h1>Welcome to my page!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <h2>some text</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Some text in content</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

The h1, h2, p tags have by default a margin underneath them. You can achieve the desired effect by using a negative margin in the containing divs or the tags themselves

(I do **not** recommend the latter like most other answers do, as it will affect every h1, h2, p tags in your page)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      background-color: green;
    }
    .container {
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-left: 10%;
      margin-right: 10%;
    }
    .head {
      background-color: gray;
      margin-bottom: -21px;
    }
    .nav {
      background-color: blue;
      margin-bottom: -21px;
    }
    .content {
      background-color: lime;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="head">
      <h1>Welcome to my page!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <h2>some text</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Some text in content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The white space is caused by the margins on your `h1`,`h2,`and `p` tags, try setting the margins to `0` like

```css
h1,h2,p{
  margin:0px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      background-color: green;
    }
    .container {
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-left: 10%;
      margin-right: 10%;
    }
    .head {
      background-color: gray;
    }
    .nav {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .content {
      background-color: lime;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="head">
      <h1>Welcome to my page!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <h2>some text</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Some text in content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `margin` on the header tags are rendered outside the containing `<div>`.

Believe it or not, but this is by design. If anyone cares to elaborate on why CSS works like this I would like to hear it. I've been working as a web-designer for 10+ years and I still make this mistake sometimes because it is so unintuitive to me.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is caused by margin on the h1,h2 and p and not on the divs, therefore all you need to do is remove those margins.
as you can see in this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3q28x6wq/)

```
h1, h2, p {
    margin:0;
}
```