# How to go fullscreen without margins

Tags: angular, material-design, fullscreen

I'm trying to figure out how to get my Angular 2 + Material Design app to be completely full width. I know M.D. isn't finished but it looks like the only thing I can do it just to manually put body's margins at 0 which does not seem like a good answer.

I tried going through the wiki for the [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki) but I guess I must be missing something.

Comment: Material design isn't concerned with your page's outer layout. Neither is Angular. This is a simple CSS question, and it seems you already know the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove margin space around body or clear default css styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547291/how-to-remove-margin-space-around-body-or-clear-default-css-styles)

Comment: [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) is what handles this now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @isherwood said it only requires a few line of css. @angular/material2 has nothing to do with that :)

```css
body, html{
  height: 100%
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
}
```